# Obtaining Subpixel Resolution for Video Processing in Python

Tags: image-processing, python, opencv, image-registration, superresolution

I am working on a video processing application to calculate distance between two points using opencv
Specs :
Linear Pixels - 1600.

FOV - 100 mm

Resolution per pixel  using above data : 62 micron

The application is realtime and I want to reduce the resolution by using subpixel mechanism.

Can you please suggest how can I reduce the resolution using subpixel mechanism in realtime?

Comment: what is a "subpixel mechanism"? What exactly is "realtime" in your case? (realtime means something different for different people) As it stands, your question is too broad. Is it really just "how do I scale a picture"?